# Cascading parse

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, tryparse

I may have the following types:
Number with decimal : 100.90
Number (int32) : 32
String : ""

What I want is a function which tries to parse as a decimal and if it fails, then tries to parse as an int and if that fails then its a string.
Any sort of function in C# which has the following functionality is appreciated.

Comment: What would this function return eventually ?

Comment: a formatted currency string if sucessully parsed as int or decimal .If not then just the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static object cascadeParse(string obj)
{
    decimal decRet;
    if (!decimal.TryParse(obj, out decRet))
    {
        int intRet;
        if (!int.TryParse(obj,  out intRet))
        {
            return obj;
        }
        else
        {
            return intRet;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return decRet;
    }
}
```

However this method will always return a `decimal` when passed something that can be parsed as an `int` as `int`s can always be parsed as `decimal`. You may want to re-order the `TryParse`s to put the `int` one first.

Answer (score 1):

[TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx)() is  your friend, however I don't understand what you want as all valid ints are also valid decimals.